# Search for a string in txt file

Tags: php, arrays

For a project I created a bash script that writes VNC ports with the corresponding VM in a text file. I'm trying to output the correct VNC port with the corresponding VM. The output of the bash script is something like:

```
 Port: 5903    VM : i-2-3-VM
 Port: 5904    VM : i-4-6-VM
 Port: 5902    VM : r-4-VM
 Port: 5901    VM : s-1-VM
 Port: 5900    VM : v-2-VM
```

The number in each line corresponds to the VNC port.

No i've got the VM name in a variable I can use, all tho I used a static value to see if my script actually works. The script outputs the entry $data variable first just as a check. The script should output "r-4-VM", i think I can fetch previous arrays to fetch the actually port later. But the script doesn't output the value im looking for in the first place. I know the value exists cause I printed $data earlier as a refference.

```
<?php
session_start();

$file = file_get_contents('/var/www/html/webpanel/text.txt');

$data = explode(' ', $file);
$array = array($data);

$count = count($array);

print_r($data);


for ($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++) { 


        if (strstr($data[$i] , 'r-4-VM')) {

            print_r($data[$i]);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: `$array = array($data)` does NOT convert your file to an array of lines. all you get is a single element array containing the entire file. if you want to auto-split that file into individual lines, then use `$array = file('/var/www/.../text.txt')`.

Comment: why not a regular expression? that seems fairly simple to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();


$array = file($file);

$count = count($array);

print_r($array);


for ($i=0; $i <= $count; $i++) { 


    if (strstr($array[$i] , 'r-4-VM')) {

        print_r($array[$i]);
}

}
?>
```

Try that.